# Is there a Preprocessor Directive exclusively for net6.0 without Platform Modifiers?

Tags: c#, .net, constants, .net-6.0, csproj

I have a library project with the following .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net6.0-windows10.0.18362;net6.0-android;net6.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In that project, I have some codes that are only available in `net6.0-windows10.0.18362`, `net6.0-android` and `net6.0-ios` (Essentially everything except `net6.0`).

I'm looking through the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives, where a table lists preprocessor directives constants based on the targeted framework. I'm specifically interested in a directive that exclusively targets net6.0+ without including the platform-specific ones like `net6.0-android` or `net6.0-ios`. Is there a directive solely for `net6.0` and + without platform modifiers?

I tried `NET` & `NET6_0_OR_GREATER`

Comment: `NET6_0` or `NET6_0_OR_GREATER` (depending on the actual use case), it is listed in the docs you have linked. What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: those two constants includes platform targets such as `net6.0-android`, `net6.0-ios` , etc. I would want a constant that only targets `net6.0`, `net7.0`, etc...

Comment: can you please show the actual problem you are trying to solve? `net6.0-android` is `net6.0` so it would be strange if it would not have included it.

Comment: I've added a bit more context in the OP.

Answer (score -1):

> I have some codes that are only available in `net6.0-windows10.0.18362`, `net6.0-android` and `net6.0-ios`

You can use conditional compilation for OS specific symbols. For example (also `NET6_0_WINDOWS_OR_GREATER` and alike should work):

```
#if WINDOWS || ANDRIOD || IOS
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
#endif
```

Or in case of everything else:

```
#if !WINDOWS && !ANDRIOD && !IOS
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
#endif
```